# ¿Cómo adquirió "pelusa" el significado de "envidia/celos"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, expresiones, sustantivos

El otro día una persona notó el comportamiento de nuestro hijo mayor en presencia del menor, y dijo:

> —Sí que tiene pelusa, ¿no?

Tardé un segundo en darme cuenta de a lo que se refería, dado que apenas había oído esa expresión, digamos que más bien la saqué por contexto. Luego ya acudí al diccionario y pude ver que, efectivamente, el significado que yo esperaba aparece en el DRAE:

> **[pelusa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SQOaGH2)**
>
> Del despect. de *pelo*.
>
> 5. f. coloq. Envidia propia de los niños.

El resto de acepciones (1-4) son las habituales (pelo tenue o menudo, o aglomeración de polvo), más una de Chile que es "niño callejero". Dejando de lado el saber si la expresión es regional o no (que también estaría bien saberlo), la pregunta más bien sería: ¿cómo ha llegado esa palabra a adquirir este significado?

Entiendo que por la tercera acepción

> 3. f. Vello tenue que aparece en la cara de las personas y en el cuerpo de los polluelos de algunas aves.

se pueda derivar algo, dado que los niños pequeños nacen con una cierta pelusilla (vello corporal muy fino), pero no entiendo cómo de ahí se ha llegado a concepto de envidia. Lo más que se me ocurre es a través de frases como "tiene celos del pelusa", siendo aquí "pelusa" una forma de llamar al niño pequeño, pero no me parece trivial el paso de ahí a "tiene pelusa". Me parece una teoría muy cogida con pinzas.

¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: Me pregunto si es un poco como *bristly* o *prickly* que son sinónimos de *irritable* en inglés.  Si alguien es alérgico a la lana, un swéter de lana se va sentir *prickly*.  El swéter le irrita la piel.  El hermano que causa celos le irrita emocionalmente.  No sé....

Answer (score 2):

Los niños pequeños son envidiosos por naturaleza. Y los niños pequeños tienen pelusa. Al decir de un niño (de manera despectiva, importante el matiz) que "tiene pelusa", se le esta llamando "inmaduro": se da a entender que no tiene aún la madurez suficiente como para, entre otras cosas, controlar esa envidia natural (ni como para haber perdido la pelusa).

Es como cuando se usa "imberbe" despectivamente para hablar de la (in)madurez de un adolescente, tenga o no tenga barba.

Comment: Entiendo que tu respuesta va por el mismo camino que la de Rodrigo, ¿no? Por el uso de "pelusa" evocando la pelusilla que te sale antes de tener vello facial de verdad.

Answer (score 1):

Aventuro la siguiente relación a falta de otra con más fundamento. Me consta que es bastante forzada.

De partida debo decir que en Chile no conocemos la expresión *pelusa* con el significado de "envidia". Aparte de las pelusas que se juntan en mis bolsillos, nosotros tenemos a los niños callejeros que mencionas. Por extensión le decimos "pelusa" o "pelusón" a cualquier niño que hace diabluras o que es molestoso. (No sé si al prócer argentino Diego Maradona le dicen "El Pelusa" por esta razón o por otra).

Ambos significados, la "envidia" y el "callejero", comparten un rasgo: estamos hablando de "niños". Se dice que el pelusa chileno debe su nombre al corte de pelo (muy corto, para evitar los piojos en los albergues infantiles), pero la verdad no he escuchado que nadie le diga de esa forma a ese tipo de corte. (A los que muestran su pobreza en cortes de pelo mal hechos les decimos *pelientos*).

En cambio sí usamos la palabra *pelusa* para referirnos a ese bozo tenue que anuncia nuestra pubertad, parecida a la pelusa que dan los pollos nuevos o los patitos, y que luego reemplazarán por las plumas del pato adulto.

La pelusa del labio no es nada lindo. Significa que eres un "cabro chico" o un "pendejito", en nada comparable con el bigote y la barba de los petulantes de la escuela, los vecinos o los primos, que se pavonean con las muchachas. De ahí que (tal vez) se haya usado la palabra "pelusa" de un modo afín al que usamos en Chile, para referirse a los varones prepúberes, con un tinte despectivo: *eres todavía un niño, das pelusa como los pollos, todavía tienes que crecer, te comportas como un bebé*. Y el rencor obtenido deriva en envidia: ganas de ser considerado igual que los mayores, tener los mismos privilegios y causar la misma admiración.

Comment: Una respuesta un tanto cogida por... las pelusas.  ¡Pero gracias por tratar de dar respuesta a esta pregunta que había quedado un tanto olvidada!

Comment: Me dio cargo de conciencia que estuviera 2 meses sin respuesta.